# Speed up 'Click to range' script possibilities?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

is there a way to speed up the execution of this script? All it does is highlight and bring you to a certain range. Currently, it takes ~2 seconds (I know, I am just being picky...). Here is what I got:

```
function goToCell() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);

  var range = sheet.getRange('A14:C16')

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);

}
```

Comment: Hyperlink? `=hyperlink("#gid=[SHEETID]&range=A14:C16")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the hyperlink formula is a little annoying because you have to hover over the box, wait for the link to pop up, and then click that. I am just looking for a quick script to add to a button and was just wondering if this was the fastest way.

Comment: You can try it like this: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A114:C116').activate();` and you can call as `google.script.run.goToCell()` from a button in the sidebar or dialog.  I don't think it's much faster if any.